# Ajax request are not async

Tags: ajax

I have an ajax problem:

```
foreach(ids as id){
  $.ajax({
    url:'script.php',
    data:'id='+id,
    cache:false,
  });
}
```

If I loop 6 times (in my foreach loop) I should have 6 asynchronous requests being made to the server. But the ajax calls in this case are called synchronously, and not asynchronously. Any one have any idea why this happens?

Comment: I've run this code in console, and I have 6 simultaneous requests:  
    for(var i=0;i<6;i++) {
      $.ajax({
        url:'script.php',
        data:'id='+i,
        cache:false,
      });
    }

Comment: using IE?  It only allows two connections at a time.  And JS isn't threaded in IE anyway... Have you tried this in other browsers?

Comment: @Sean, IE has supported async AJAX calls since IE 5. Well before any other browser even had support or knew of anything called AJAX

Comment: @Shiv Kumar, I know it's supported "async" but it's doing activex magic behind the scenes to make it async. Javascript is not threaded in the traditional sense in IE.

Comment: @Sean well as far is the OPs question is concerned IE is Async isn't not (making an AJAX call)? So then your comment is moot (at least as far as the question is concerned. Besides, since IE7 XMLHTtpRequests are not implemented using ActiveX.

Comment: @Shiv Kumar, IE still limits to 2 requests at any given time... so the others will block.

Comment: @Sean, IE 8 has a limit of 8 FF has a limit of 6. In fact every browser has a limit of between 6-10. The limit changes depending on the kind of connection (broadband or dial up). Just to be clear, these limits are per domain (which is relevant to this question) but just thought I'd put it out there. And these limits are not only for XmlHttpRequests but for all requests no matter how you make the request.

Comment: Picking nits, but IE8 is 6, not 8 by default.  IE7 and before is 2.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282402  It's not a big deal, but we can both agree that the OP shouldn't be doing this in a loop, right?

Comment: Whether or not to use this in a loop depends on the use case.

Comment: I'm still waiting the question of how he has determined they are synchronous calls.

Comment: they are syncronyous calls because the success functions of ajax fire in order to the loop order, but i found the solution , it was a problem with the php script now i am posting it...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok thanks. After some hours of analysing and reflecting I realized why this script goes syncronsly: I open the script.php file and I notice this and the beginig of the file:

```
<?php
session_start();
$var1=$_SESSION['SOMEVAR'];
.......
//do php script.....

.......
?>
```

So I have parallel ajax calls to a php script that uses session, but sessions in this case locks the calls to be executed syncrosnly cause of the session vars request, so the solution of this problem is:

```
<?php
session_start();
$var1=$_SESSION['SOMEVAR'];
//get all session var
......
session_write_close();//then close it
.......
//do php script.....

.......
?>
```

With session_write_close i have my script to make the ajax calls in async way. a good explain here http://konrness.com/php5/how-to-prevent-blocking-php-requests/

Comment: Great! thanx.. and I was confused.. I thought that I had to use multitasking in order to accomplish this..

Answer (score 1):

Why not sending all id's to the script and then loop them is faster en more accurate..

Javascript:

```
// you can send the whole array in once i think not for sure
$.ajax({
    url:'script.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: ids,
    cache:false,
    success:function(msg)
    {
        // when done
    }
});
```

script.php:

```
foreach($_POST as $id)
{
    [............] // do your thing
}
```

Comment: No i cant do this, because each request must be indipendent.

Comment: You can watch to this tutorial maybe there is something in here that can help you : http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/asynchronous-comments-with-jquery-and-json/

Comment: it's a begginer guides, normally i would follow you suggestion when to make multiple request in one with ajax, but in that case i needed parallel request

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with setting the async parameter to true?

```
foreach(ids as id)
{
  $.ajax({
  url:'script.php',
  async: true,
  data:'id='+id,
  cache:false,
  });
}
```

How have you confirmed that the calls are synchronous and not async?

Comment: i have try this but nothing changes, in fact request are asyncs but response are sync.. see my solution answer

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
session_start();
$var1=$_SESSION['SOMEVAR'];
//get all session var
......
session_write_close();//then close it
.......
//do php script.....

.......
?>
```

That's awesome, it solved my issue the same as albanx, thanks