# Codeigniter long polling blocking other ajax requests

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, long-polling

I want to achieve a pseudo real time chat app inside a Codeigniter framework using long polling. I know it's not the best option (I could try with HTML5 Websocket), but I'm on a cPanel shared account so I don't have any privileges on installing anything

So, let's get back to the issue itself.
Basically, I use a .js file similar to the one below:

```
    //get server time
    var time;
    $.ajax( {
         url: JS_BASE_URL + 'admin/users/get_time',
         success: function( dataResponse ) {
             time = dataResponse;
        },
        type: 'GET'
    } ); 
    //long polling AJAX 
    function getNewMsgs() {
        $.ajax( {
            url: JS_BASE_URL + 'admin/users/get_new_msgs',
            type: 'POST',
            // send the time
            data: { time: time, sender_id: sender_id },
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true, /* If set to non-async, browser shows page as "Loading.."*/
            cache: false,
            success: function( dataResponse ) {
                // update the time
                time = dataResponse.time;
                // show the new messages
                dataResponse.msgs.forEach( function( msg ) {
                    preparePost('in', (msg.date_sent), msg.sender_id, 'avatar3', msg.message);        
                } );
                // repeat
                setTimeout( getNewMsgs(), 1000 );
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                setTimeout( getNewMsgs(), 1000 );    
            }                   
        } );
    }
    getNewMsgs(); // this one is on the document ready
```

The php get_new_msgs function in Users controller:

```
function get_new_msgs() {    
    echo json_encode( array(
        'msgs' => $this->aauth->start_polling($this->aauth->get_user()->id),
        // response again the server time to update the "js time variable"
        'time' => time() 
    ) );
    die();
}
```

And the model function start_polling:

```
function start_polling($receiver_id) {
    // get the time
    $time      = $this->CI->input->post( 'time' );
    $sender_id = $this->CI->input->post( 'sender_id' );

    // some crappy validation
    if( !is_numeric( $time ) ) {
        return array();
    }

    $time = date('Y-m-d G:i:s',$time);
    // -> 2010-10-01
    //$time = $time['year'] + '-' + $time['mon'] + '-' + $time['mday'];

    while( true ) {

        $where = 'date_sent >= "' . $time . '" AND ((receiver_id=' . $receiver_id . ' AND pm_deleted_receiver IS NULL AND sender_id=' . $sender_id . ' AND pm_deleted_sender IS NULL) OR (receiver_id=' . $sender_id . ' AND pm_deleted_receiver IS NULL AND sender_id=' . $receiver_id . ' AND pm_deleted_sender IS NULL))'; 
        $query = $this->aauth_db->where($where);
        $query = $this->aauth_db->order_by('id','ASC');
        $query = $this->aauth_db->get( $this->config_vars['pms']);
        //die($this->aauth_db->last_query());
        if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ) {
            $result = $query->result();
            if ($this->config_vars['pm_encryption']){
                $this->CI->load->library('encrypt');

                foreach ($result as $k => $r)
                {
                    $result[$k]->title   = $this->CI->encrypt->decode($r->title);
                    $result[$k]->message = $this->CI->encrypt->decode($r->message);
                }
            }
            echo json_encode($result);
            die();


 } else {
        sleep( 1 );
        continue;    
    }
}
```

}

Now, the issue is that whenever I run the page with the chat, a request is loaded and waiting for a response from the server. But, no other requests will finish.. it seems that the other requests sent after the long polling are waiting for that first one to finish.. Even if I stop the script, the page will load very slow..

Any idea on what I'm missing?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: yes, the `PHP session` is blocking your requests. You should call `session_write_close` inside `function get_new_msgs()`

Comment: And what happens to the CI session? Does it affect the current user's session?

Comment: No, after you call the `session_write_close` you can not modify the `$_SESSION` but the user stays logged.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900214/ajax-request-are-not-async/4903453#4903453